# Show/Hide Profile picture on each row based on Employee Name?

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have found a simple script that allows for hiding or showing a picture using the text in a shape. I like the functionality and would like to apply it to our list of employees. However, the way it is constructed right now would require me to add one macro for each person and that is not sustainable in the long run.

Is there a way to re-write this script so it **sets the name of the picture based on the name of the employee** that is located in column A? Then it would be really simple to just insert images and name them with the Employee name.

I also see that the button is mentioned in the code. So this also needs to be written more dynamically. Could I use a normal format control instead of a shape? (The button does not need to change the displayed text as in this script.)

I really would appreciate your help here. This would look really smooth and I think others would make good use of a VBA like this too.

```
Sub Macro1()
 With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
 
   'Check if shape text is equal to "Hide"
   If .Text = "Hide" Then
 
      'Change shape text to "Show"
      .Text = "Show"
 
      'Hide shape
      ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
 
   'Continue here if shape is not equal to "Hide"
   Else
 
      'Change text to "Hide"
      .Text = "Hide"

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 4")
 
         'Move image named "Picture1" based to lower right corner of shape
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Left = .Left + .Width
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Top = .Top + .Height
 
         'Show image
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True
      End With
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Reference: https://www.get-digital-help.com/show-and-hide-a-picture-vba/

Example data:
[image: PrintScreen from the Excel Layout]

Comment: It is definitely a good idea to make your method more generalized and reusable. I'm not very clear on what exactly you are trying to apply this to. "...and would like to apply it to our list of employees" leaves many questions for me. Do you have an excel sheet with employee names and a picture for each of them? (20 employees with 20 pictures?)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have a list of names and some further info about each person. The pictures are right now stored in a separate disc. I can insert them anyway needed for this script to work.

Comment: but what is supposed to happen here? How does the picture hiding/showing come into play? Is it something like a user selects the name in column A and then the related picture is supposed to show while all others hide?

Comment: So, are you simply after a script that renames the image in say, B1 with the text in A1.. image in B2 with the text in A2.. etc.? - i.e. the whole hide/show element of the script is irrelevant?

Comment: I added a picture that might explain it. I would like to be able to hide/show (or just apply a popup if this is better) to show the profile picture of each Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to say that you would be much better off designing something like this in MS Access as opposed to Excel. There are lots of tutorials showing how to build exactly this with Access Forms. It would certainly be much easier to maintain.

That being said, your question was about doing this in Excel and I'll answer that with a simple implementation suggestion. Just bare in mind, it comes with what I would consider "messy" maintenance.

First, you have a bunch of shapes representing the show/hide buttons. Each of these shapes would need to have their own unique name (not important what the name is for this case) and each of them would need to be positioned inside the cell for the row they are meant to operate on (as shown in your example photo).

Next, each employee's photo would need to be named the same as your employee name (the value in column A in your example).

Lastly, you would need to set the "Assigned Macro" of each show/hide button to the same method (I've named my `Button_Click()`). That method implementation looks like this:

```
Sub Button_Click()
    Dim clickedButton As Shape
    Dim employeePhoto As Shape
    Dim clickedButtonRow As Long
    Dim employeeName As String
    
    '// gets the row number in whcih the clicked button resides
    Set clickedButton = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    clickedButtonRow = clickedButton.TopLeftCell.Row
    
    '// gets the employee name (column A in this case)
    employeeName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & clickedButtonRow).Value
    Set employeePhoto = ActiveSheet.Shapes(employeeName)
    
    With clickedButton
        
        ' //set the position of the employee photo
        employeePhoto.Top = .Top + .Height
        employeePhoto.Left = .Left + .Width
        
        With .TextFrame.Characters
            '// set the visibility of the associated employee picture based on the text state of the button
            employeePhoto.Visible = .Text = "Show"
            
            '// swap the label on the button
            If ActiveSheet.Shapes(employeeName).Visible Then
                .Text = "Hide"
            Else
                .Text = "Show"
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! :-) This solved my question. 

It might seem like a lot upkeep from your perspective. However this solution enables a person not familiar with VBA to simply update this document with new pictures. Great!

Answer (score 0):

When applying the solution from **ArcherBird** I discovered a need to add a button in the headline to **hide/show all pictures**. This provides for a better user experience.

I added this script to the sheet (not in a module) and connected it to a button.
In my document I have our company logo in the headline and I kept this visible at all times.

I hope somebody find this set-up useful! :-)

```
Dim c As Boolean
Sub Button4_Click()
 c = c Xor True
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.Visible = c
 ActiveSheet.Pictures("CompanyLogo").Visible = True
End Sub
```